# Set an existing signature in a X509 certificate using OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl

I am reconstructing X509 certificates in OpenSSL from a [custom format](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-8974-CryptoAuth-ATECC-Compressed-Certificate-Definition-ApplicationNote.pdf). Is there a clean way to put an existing signature into a certificate instead of signing from a private key (using `X509_sign()`)?

I'd like to avoid [dirty solutions like `memcpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665900/put-signature-on-a-x509-certificate) and use only the OpenSSL API. The next goal is to call it from Python.

I noticed a few extra APIs like `X509_sign_ctx()` and `X509_REQ_sign()`. Is it possible to pass an existing signature within the context with `X509_sign_ctx()`? Maybe another option would be to generate a response to the certificate signing request that is then passed to `X509_REQ_sign()`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question: the signature of a certificate is computed on the `tbscertificate` in DER format. If you copy an alternate signature, it will not correspond to the certificate, and any SSL verification will reject it.
Is that signature copied form a previous X.509 certificate?

Comment: I want to "reconstruct" a X509 certificate from a [Compressed Certificate](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-8974-CryptoAuth-ATECC-Compressed-Certificate-Definition-ApplicationNote.pdf). I currently sign the certificate with a fake key and then replace the ASN.1 signature by editing the binary certificate using the techniques described in the section 3.2 Signature Reconstruction.

Comment: *"next goal is to call it from Python"* - why have you tagged it as [tag:C] then?

Comment: This was just to give some context. Since the solution (if any) will rely on the OpenSSL C API, it is not important. Do you suggest to remove this part from the question?